# on image click show text which is behind image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an image slider. I want to make it so when the user clicks on the image it should get hidden and  i.e text which is behind the image should be visible.

In my image's OnClick event I have written code to hide the image, but what to do if I want it to be visible again when the user clicks again on that or any other option?

Comment: Well since you've tagged the question with "jquery" presumably you're using `.hide()` or `.fadeOut()` or similar for the hiding code that you've already written, so the opposite would be `.show()` or `.fadeIn()`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery SlideToggle() or show() and hide() method like this:

```
    <div id="yourid"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnid').click(function(){
             $('#divid').show();

         });
         $('#btnid2').click(function(){
             $('#divid).hide();
         });
    });
```

Comment: <script >
$(document).hover(function () {
    $('#gallery img').click(function() {
       
        $(this).hide("slow");
        },function(){
        $this.show()
        
    });
    
});
</script>
if i am doing this way once image disapear it is not visible again on mousemovement .

Comment: what should be #btnid2 in my pgm ?

Comment: Change `hover` to `ready`. And if you want hover event to fire function used `hover` to `click` like this:

<script > $(document).`ready`(function () { $('#gallery img').`hover`(function() { $(this).hide("slow"); },function(){ `$(this)`.show() }); }); </script>

Comment: I recommend this please check this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: i have tried this hover .. image doesn;t come visible again .

Answer (score 0):

In your onclick event you can create a one time click event on document which will show image again.

This will display image when user clicks outside also.

Make sure that click event on document is one time only to avoid unnecessary action.

Comment: <script >
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#gallery img').hover(function() {
       
        $(this).hide("slow");
        },function(){
        $this.show()
        
    });
    
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Similar to fadeToggle you can just use toggle(speed). This will switch between display none and block.

```
$(document).on('click','#imageContainer',function(){
    $('#image').toggle();
)};
```

Comment: i have tried toggle () option but it is not working .. same image goes invisible and not coming again <script >
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#gallery img').click(function() {
       
        $(this).toggle();
       
        
    });
    
});

Comment: Because you are applying the toggle event to the actual image. You need to have a container on top of the image which acts as the "object" to click on. <div id="imageContainer"><img src="#" id="image" /><p>text</p></div>

Comment: yes i have container name "gallery" if i will use gallery then all the images of slide will disappear..  i want to hide one particular image on which user click